# Unable to install iOS Simulator 8.4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b), OS X v 10.10.4 and the iOS Simulator just does not show up in Preferences:
[image]

If I click "Check and Install now" nothing happens.
I have an another machine next to me and everything is installed correctly.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6.4 comes with the iOS 8.4 Simulator runtime.

A default set of devices should be created automatically.  If you deleted them, you can recreate them with Xcode's Devices Window or from the command line using `xcrun simctl create ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some simulator use Xcode Window/Devices then click + icon at left bottom. You can add any installed simulator to your xcode.